# How to return an empty list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to call a function that will empty two lists that i send as arguments. 
How do i go about emptying the lists within the function and making sure they are empty once the code comes to reuse them in the original function in Python? Below is the code i am using as a test run for a larger system.

```
def Input():
    nextRound = ['Dad', 'Mom']
    maleNames = ['son', 'James', 'Mick', 'Dad']

    a = int(input('Enter a number please'))
    if a == 1:
        ErrorInput(1, nextRound, maleNames )
        # I want the below to print two empty strings
        print(nextRound, maleNames)

def ErrorInput(error, namelist, round):


    if error == 1:
        print('ERROR: You have entered a number above what is impossible to 
        score')
        namelist = []
        round = []
    elif error == 2:
        print('ERROR: You Have entered a score meaning both players win')
        namelist = []
        round = []
    elif error == 3:
        print('ERROR: You have entered a score meaning neither of the two 
        players win')
        namelist = []
        round = []
    elif error == 4:
        print('EEROR: You have entered a negative number, this is 
        impossible')
        namelist = []
        round = []

    return(namelist, round)

Input()
```

Comment: I don't follow how your code relates to your question. I also don't understand why you are doing this, can you clarify?

Comment: I do not understand either, but just replace your line 7 with `nextRound, maleNames = ErrorInput(1, nextRound, maleNames)` to update them

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't `aList = []` 'emptying' the list called `aList` for you?

Comment: What i want is for when i run the code and i enter 1 as the input it runs the if statement within the ErrorInput function and sends the two lists as arguments and makes them equal (= [ ]) to nothing and returns them so that when i print (nextRound and maleNames) in the input function it prints two empty strings. As right now it prints them with the values i set at the start.

Comment: @Nae That creates a new list and binds it to the same name, `aList.clear()` would empty it

Comment: @Chris_Rands .clear has worked a treat, thank you.

Comment: @EthanVenencia OK, the best way to thank, however, is to accept an answer that works. This will give you a bit of reputation but it will also inform the community that this question is successfully answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `namelist.clear()` to clear a list

Answer (score 2):

Here, I took the liberty to tidy up the code.

```
def start():  # don't use the name input()
    nextRound = ['Dad', 'Mom']
    maleNames = ['son', 'James', 'Mick', 'Dad']

    a = int(input('Enter a number please'))
    if a == 1:
        nextRound, maleNames = ErrorInput(1, nextRound, maleNames)  # if you want nextRound, maleNames to be [] you have to assign it to them
        print(nextRound, maleNames)

def ErrorInput(error, namelist, round):
    error_codes = {1: 'ERROR: You have entered a number above what is impossible to score', 2: 'ERROR: You Have entered a score meaning both players win',3: 'ERROR: You have entered a score meaning neither of the two players win', 4: 'ERROR: You have entered a negative number, this is impossible'}  # too many ifs makes one wonder if a dictionary is the way to go
    print(error_codes.get(error, 'Unknown Error'))
    return([], [])  # return the empty lists.

start()
```

Not sure why you go to such lengths to just get `[], []` but whatever floats your boat.

---

Take a look at the notes on the code to get a better feeling of why I made the changes.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment above, i don't follow your code.  But to iteratively empty a list try:

```
while len(maleNames) !=0:
    popped = maleNames.pop()
    print('Popped value: ', popped, '\tNew list: ', maleNames)
```

Comment: @NickA Thank you, yes.